# The parameter marked [FromBody] always null

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

This problem is truly incomprehensible. What is available:

- ASP NET Web API 4.8.
- IIS 10.0.
- Complex type which has 3 large string fields - photos in base64 (and other fields, but I think the problem is not in them)
- POST method in which a variable of complex type is marked with an `[FromBody]` attribute
- `NRE` due to the fact that the complex type parameter in the method comes as null

I send requests via Postman and the application that uses my API sends requests with a json body. The raw being sent is correct. But when it comes to calling the method, I get an object containing null instead of a deserialized object. According to my assumptions, this arises due to the fact that the base64 strings I mentioned are too large (and this was indeed confirmed by sending empty strings instead of real base64). But I set the `maxAllowedContentLength` parameter via `Web.config` as large as possible. This had no effect.

The most interesting thing in this situation is that on-premises and on the test server to the same version of the code all works fine. What could I miss?
P. S Note funny the situation - after you restart the website in IIS, the first query in this method worked fine, then threw NRE

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the **`uploadReadAheadSize`** parameter to 30 MB, the method worked properly.
With similar complex and large objects and queries, it is worth considering the settings in Web.Config such as

1. **`maxRequestLength`**
2. **`maxAllowedContentLength`**
3. **`uploadReadAheadSize`**
4. **`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"`**